# Prevent other database restore from in stored proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-restore

Assume that there two Sql Server databases on a server, Backup and Analysis. Backup is in Standby mode and periodically has logs applied to it. There is a long-running stored procedure on Analysis that accesses tables in Backup. If Backup goes into a restore during the stored proc, the stored proc fails. (I am not concerned with the case where Backup is already in a restore when the stored proc starts.)

There are a number of ways of dealing with this issue, such as scheduling the stored procedure and restore so as not to happen during the same time period or breaking the stored procedure up into smaller stored procedures. However, what I would like to do is to prevent Backup from going into a restore (probably by preventing the restore process from obtaining exclusive access) throughout the duration of the stored proc. I have tried calling Backup.sys.sp_getapplock to obtain and hold an application lock during the stored proc, but that did not prevent the restore from occurring.

Is there any way in which I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that the Backup database is in read-only mode as part of a log shipping config?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using log shipping on Backup, you set it to only apply t-logs when there are no user connections to the database.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189572(v=sql.105).aspx

> You can choose not to disconnect users. In this case, the restore job
>   cannot restore transaction log backups to the secondary database if
>   there are users connected to that database. Transaction log backups
>   will accumulate until there are no user connections to the database.

Comment: I'm not sure that this solution would work. The process in question is run on the Analysis database, not the Backup database. As such, there will not necessarily be any connections to Backup when the restore job begins.